# How to write case in where statement in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

i need to write case statement in inner where, the condition is something like.

```
"If color equel to 'RED' then return all the flowers including red" 
 else "return all flowers which are not RED"
```

I need to include this statement in where clause, my where statement looks something like this

```
Select Plant, leafs, places
from dbo.tblplant, dbo.tblflower,dbo.tblplaces
where dbo.tblplant = ID and
dbo.tblplaces = PLACE and
dbo.tblflower = REDCOLOR.
```

Instead of redcolor i need modify in such a way that query should return all flowers if its red, else it should exclude the red color one and return rest.

Comment: `WHERE ( @Color = 'Red' ) OR ( @Color <> 'Red' AND Flower.Color <> 'Red' )` ?

Comment: Where is "color"/"it" coming from? Is it a variable passed to this query?

Comment: Yes sure, its passed as parameter to SP

Comment: Use `join`, not `where` to join tables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
where  @colorParameter = 'RED' 
       or ( @colorParameter <> 'RED' and tblplant.color <> 'RED')
```

Comment: Case statement is not required?

Comment: @LLL - it's a surprisingly common mistake that people quite new to SQL assume they need `CASE` when in fact they just need to apply simple boolean logic.